# Auto Launch bootstrap 2.3.2 modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Hello I was wondering if there was some javascript to auto launch the modal window within bootstrap 2.3.2.  I am using the modal window for a form and the code for the from is on page and I want the modal window to open back up on the event of an error in the form. My code works fine and it shows the error message in the modal window bu you have to relaunch the window to see it so users may not necessarily know they have errors, so that's my dilemma.

Is there a way to do this?  The page isn't refreshing so I can't say load it when the page loads, as I have seen that before.

Comment: Actually, when you want show modal and when you need to close it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To launch your modal you can use the following call in javascript/jQuery

```
$('#myModal').modal();
```

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do that but as it turns out it was just as simple as me putting the launch code above my javascript sources so it was run before the html loaded the javascript.